# Rails Module not 'included' when included by a Rails Model Class (in Production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, include, require, production

Heres my sample rails model class (in app/models/user.rb):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  puts "loading user model"
  include Auth::User # module is in the Auth engine
end
```

Heres that module in an engine named auth (file is in vendor/engines/app/models/auth/user.rb)

```
module Auth
  module User
    puts "loading module"
    self.included(base)
      puts "module is included"
    end
  end
end
```

When rails (3.1.1 ruby 1.92) starts (in NON-development), I see "loading user model" and "loading module" but do not see the "module is included".

If I change the name of the module and the filename from models/auth/user.rb to say user_auth.rb I MAY see the "included" if the module is included "early enough" in the rails init process (see below). I would like to keep the module's name and filename as User. I see no reason to have to change this. And it should not matter when I load the User model (and when the User model includes the auth/user module).

Note: When I say "MAY" above, this is what I observe: if rails "happens" to need to load a UsersController then it will just happen to load the User object and that will include the User module ONLY if I rename the user module to UserAuth (or something that is not the same name as the model name). I "happen" to load the UsersController because of routes. I know this because of a stacktrace I printed. So I can get the module to be included by 1) renaming the module and 2) forcing it to load with a controller.

Note: Continuing... the module is only loaded if the class thats including it is loaded/required sometime EARLY in the rails startup process. This is why forcing the User model to load "early" by forcing rails to "see" the UsersController (because of loading the routes) will also include the auth/user module.

Note: If I run the console (again, in non-development mode) and then do a require 'user' the module is NOT included. So, if I "wait" till after rails is fully loaded, when I require User, the auth/user module is not included. I think this is a bit inaccurate, I see the User model loaded during rails init process and I see the auth/user module being loaded but DO NOT see the auth/user module being included at that time. I ONLY see the module being included if the user model is loaded "early" in rails init process. Or maybe its "loaded at some magic time in the rails init process).

Can anyone shed some light? Ive tried many different things to get the module to be included, such as opening the User class and re-including the module. This seemed to work sometimes but not consistently.

Comment: I renamed my auth-based modules and now rails/ruby includes the modules. In the above code, `module User` became `module UserAuth`. This seems to avoid whatever confusion is happening and the modules is included in the class. Next I'm going to have my engine require the module file `../app/models/auth/user.rb' so I dont have to rely on the controller being loaded to load the module.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this to your model in the first line before the class definition?

```
 load "#{Rails.root}/vendor/engines/app/models/auth/user.rb"
```

Comment: I get something like this: LoadError: Expected .../vendor/engines/auth/app/models/auth/user.rb to define User. This leads me to believe that I cannot have my module named the same as my class. Seems like a severe limitation to me.

Comment: you know, i think i've actually run into this bug before. rails has a hard time dealing with namespaces especially when they conflict with a model of the same name on the bottom layer. sorry i can't be more help than this..